# Comparing 2 CSV files using python with different rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, csv

I have two csv file say one.csv and two.csv. Format of file is One.csv:

```
ID1 , att 1 , att 2
```

for two.csv

```
ID2, att2, att1
```

Now i want to print ID1 ,ID 2 ,att1, att2 wherever att1 and att2 are same. I've written this code but it prints only one such case But there are a lot more cases like this

```html
import csv
path1 ="/home/vishver/Desktop/"
file1 =open(path1 +"one.csv","r")
file2 =open(path1 +"two.csv","r")

reader1 =csv.reader(file1)
reader2 =csv.reader(file2)
count =0
for line1 in reader1:
 for line2 in reader2: 
  if line1[1] == line2[2] or line1[2] == line2[1]:
   t=line2[0],line1[0],line1[1],line1[2]   
   print(t)
   count+=1
 
print count
```

Comment: Can you use Pandas? Seems like the easiest way to me.

Comment: Move `reader2 =csv.reader(file2)` inside outer for loop.

Comment: @Ilayaraja tried! it did not help

Comment: @ncfirth any pointers on how to do it using pandas

Comment: @user3767047 it's probably about creating two pandas data frames of your csvs then [joining](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) them on id, then doing some simple operation on the resulting joined data frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the total count of common attributes than try this:

```
path1 ="/home/vishver/Desktop/"
file1 =open(path1 +"one.csv","r")
file2 =open(path1 +"two.csv","r")

reader1 =csv.reader(file1)
reader2 =csv.reader(file2)

count =0
file1_att1 = []
file1_att2 = []
file2_att1 = []
file2_att2 = []


for line1 in reader1:
    file1_att1.append(line[1])
    file1_att2.append(line[2])

for line1 in reader1:
    file2_att1.append(line[1])
    file2_att2.append(line[2])

common1 = (set(file1_att1).intersection(file2_att2))
common2 = (set(file1_att2).intersection(file2_att1))

print common1+common2
```

Comment: how would i get the corresponding id1 and id2?

Comment: @user3767047 run forloop over common1 and common2 attributes list and findout corresponding id1 and id2 from file1 and file2 respectively.